# Cant map route Correctly using Zend Frameworkd 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Here is my dump for route upon which i want to route my app.

```
[album] => Array([route] => Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment Object
                            (
                                [parts:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => literal
                                                [1] => /album
                                            )
                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => optional
                                                [1] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => literal
                                                                [1] => /
                                                            )
                                                        [1] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => parameter
                                                                [1] => action
                                                                [2] => 
                                                            )
                                                    )
                                            )
                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => optional
                                                [1] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => literal
                                                                [1] => /
                                                            )
                                                        [1] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => parameter
                                                                [1] => id
                                                                [2] => 
                                                            )
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )
                                [regex:protected] => /album(?:/(?P[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*))?(?:/(?P[0-9]+))?
                                [paramMap:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [param1] => action
                                        [param2] => id
                                    )
                                [defaults:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [controller] => Album\Controller\Album
                                        [action] => index
                                    )
                                [assembledParams:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                    )
                            )
                        [priority] => 0
                        [serial] => 3
                    )
```

But when i try this

```
  $router = $e->getRouter();
  $url = $router->assemble(array(), array('name' => 'Album\index'));
```

i get following error.

> Route with name "Album\index" not found

```
 Edit: here is route settings from module.config

   'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id' => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

EDIT: As advised i made following changes

```
  'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/album',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => 'index',
//                        'id' => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'process' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/[:action]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

but now i cant seem to pass index action. I mean the only action of album module visible to me is index and none else can some 1 correct/suggest what must be done?

Comment: Please provide route-configuration as written inside `module.config.php`. From what i can see now, the only route defined is called `album` and **not** `Album/index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i guessed, a route `Album\index` does not exist. This is your configuration:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(  //<-- THIS is the ROUTE_NAME
```

What you're looking for is this:

```
// AlbumController::indexAction()
$this->url('album');
$this->url('album', array('action' => 'index');

// AlbumController::listAction()
$this->url('album', array('action' => 'list');

// AlbumController::editAction() with param ID = 3
$this->url('album', array('action' => 'edit', 'id' => 3);
```

The Syntax you used is for `child_routes`. See this example

```
'router'       => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album'     => array(
            'type'          => 'literal',
            'options'       => array(
                'route'    => '/album',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'album-controller-album',
                    'action'     => 'index'
                )
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes'  => array(
                'list'   => array(
                    'type'    => 'literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/list',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'list'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

And the associated routing:

```
//AlbumController::indexAction()
$this->url('album');

//AlbumController::listAction()
$this->url('album/list');
```

Comment: 'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*', dosent this help making any action to be parent? as u can see i am not using any child. Moreover if i just pass "Album" as URL wont it redirect me to default as i am doing?

Comment: Please see this: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#http-route-types and http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.quick-start.html#create-a-route This should give you a better understanding of routing.

Comment: i now made following changes